# Displaying Symbolic Variable Name as LaTeX in Julia

Tags: julia, latex, symbolic-math

I am working with Julia and the Symbolics package to display variable names as LaTeX. I have a variable defined with a LaTeX-like name using the **`@variables`** macro:

```
Pkg.add("Symbolics")
using Symbolics

@variables var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}"
```

I would like to display this variable name as LaTeX, but when I use **`display(var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}")`**, it shows the value of the variable rather than the LaTeX expression. I want to display the variable name like using the **`L""`** string :

```
L"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}" |> display
```

Is there a way to display this symbolic variable name as LaTeX, so it shows the variable name itself.

I have tried the following approaches to display the symbolic variable **`var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}"`** as LaTeX:

I attempted to display the variable:

```
front = "L\""
back = '"'
eval(print(front, :(var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}") ,back)) |> display
```

but it did not work.

I expect that I can use metaprogramming to display the symbolic variable **`var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}"`** as LaTeX i.e. as output of **`L"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}" |> display`**, showing the variable name itself, **`var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}"`**.

My expectation is to find a solution or an alternative approach that allows me to display the symbolic variable name as LaTeX, preserving the variable's LaTeX-like formatting.

Comment: Your example is working in a Jupyter notebook (just the first three lines of code). What exactly is the problem, where and how do you want to render the LaTeX? Btw: Symbolics.jl does support Latexify.jl for getting some more complex LaTeXString out of your equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

First, by specifying the MIME of the output, you can get the variable to be displayed as a LaTeX equation:

```
julia> x = (@variables var"\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}")[1]
var"\\frac{\\partial y}{\\partial x}"

julia> display("text/latex", x)
$$ \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
 $$
```

You can also turn the variable into a `Symbol` (by calling [`Symbol`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.Symbol)) and then a `LaTeXString` (by calling `LaTeXStrings.jl`’s [`latexstring`](https://github.com/JuliaStrings/LaTeXStrings.jl)), which will get you the LaTeX in inline form.

```
julia> latexstring(Symbol(x))
L"$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$"
```

Comment: I believe you need to `use LaTeXStrings` for the last option.